# Change a positive number in to a negative number in a function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, return

I've been looking around on the internet about my problem but can't seem to find any help.

The problem is that you should have a random list of numbers and then return the list, however, the given number should be negative instead of positive when returned. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
def change_sign(list,n):
    if n in list1:
        return list1  #Don't know what to put here
    elif n not in list1:
        print("The number is not in the list")
```

So if the given number (n) is in the list, it should return the same list but with n as a negative number instead.

Hope this makes sense, I would be extremely grateful if anyone could find the time to help me!

Comment: you can make a number negative by multiplying by -1: `n * -1`

Comment: @Hamms you don't need multiplication to negate a number; you just need the minus sign: `-n`

Comment: Bad idea to have a parameter called `list`.  It masks the built-in constructor for a list: `list()`.  Did you mean `list1`?

Comment: What if the number is already negative?  Should a negative number be returned as positive or negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
def change_sign(list1,n):
    if n in list1:
        return [-i if i==n else i for i in list1]
    elif n not in list1:
        print("The number is not in the list")
```

does this answer your question?

List comprehensions are extremely powerful! Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to iterate through the list, and compare each item to your given number.

```
def change_sign(list, n):
    new_list = []
    for value in list:
        if value == n:
            value = -value
        new_list.append(value)

    return new_list
```

You can clean this up using a list comprehension:

```
def change_sign(list, n):
    return [value if value != n else -value for value in list]
```

Don't worry if you don't understand this, it will be covered in a later exercise.

Answer (score 0):

If we're returning a new list this will do it for you (also don't use the word list as a variable, it's a reserved word!):

```
def change_sign(numbers_list,invert_this_number):
    inverted_numbers_list = []
    for number in numbers_list:
        if number == invert_this_number:
            inverted_numbers_list.append(number * -1)
        else:
            inverted_numbers_list.append(number)
    return inverted_numbers_list


>>> change_sign([-1,1,3],-1)
[1, 1, 3]
```

You could probably do some fancy operators, like doing a bitwise operations on the integer itself, but this simple code snippet should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a new list using `list comprehensions` or `map`

```
n = 5
old_list = [0, 4, 3, -2, 5, -5, 6]
new_list = [-i if i == n else i for i in old_list]
# OR
new_list = map(lambda i: -i if i == n else i, old_list)
```

Or if you absolutely need it in function form:

```
def func(old_list, n):
    return [-i if i == n else i for i in old_list]
```

Be aware that these all expect `n` to be a positive number.  If you want it to handle positive and negative numbers (a negative number would return an essentially unchanged list)

```
def func(old_list, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return old_list[:]
    return [-i if i == n else i for i in old_list]
```